# Org mode display of elisp functions

Tags: org-mode

I make a lot of notes in org-mode including emacs and elisp notes.
If I put the following in an org file I would like the find-grep-dired to be highlighted similar to how it is in a *Help* buffer. It doesn't necessarily have to provide a link like *Help* does but that would be an added bonus.

`find-grep-dired'   find all files containing a grep match

Is there an easy way to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not a direct answer to your question, but Org has a built-in concept of [links](http://orgmode.org/manual/External-links.html#External-links) that can be used for elisp commands and other things. Links are displayed in a certain way and can be followed using the command `org-open-at-point` (`C-c C-o`).

If you are looking at the *Help* buffer for a command, try invoking `org-store-link`. Then switch to an org buffer and call `org-insert-link` (`C-c C-l`). This will create a link to that documentation.

You can create help and lisp links, e.g.

```
;; link to command help, displays "help:find-grep-dired"
[[help:find-grep-dired]]

;; link to command help, displays "find-grep-dired"
[[help:find-grep-dired][find-grep-dired]]

;; link to execute command, displays "elisp:find-grep-dired"
[[elisp:find-grep-dired]]

;; link to execute lisp form, displays "find foobar"
[[elisp:(find-grep-dired "~/org" foobar)][find foobar]]
```

Comment: I figured links would be the way to do it. Unfortunately I have a lot of notes where I didn't insert a link. But I think I will go through and make them links because it is good practice. Thanks for providing a good explanation!

Answer (score 3):

I wrote https://github.com/jkitchin/scimax/blob/master/emacs-keybinding-command-tooltip-mode.el for this. It highlights things using the emacs documentation syntax:  [find-file] and `find-file'. The first one shows the keybinding, and the second shows the docstring in tooltips, and both are clickable to open the help.